# Proof for a construction of excenters

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangle-centres

#### Problem

[image]

Let $I$ be the incenter of $\Delta ABC$. Produce $AI$, $BI$ and $CI$ to $J_A$, $J_B$ and $J_C$ respectively such that $J_BAJ_C$, $J_CBJ_A$ and $J_ACJ_B$ are straight lines. Prove that $J_A$, $J_B$ and $J_C$ are the excenters of $\Delta ABC$.

#### Solution by using barycentric coordinates

Let $|BC|=a$, $|CA|=b$ and $|AB|=c$. Recall that in barycentric coordinates (not necessarily normalised), $A=(1,0,0)$, $B=(0,1,0)$, $C=(0,0,1)$ and $I=(a,b,c)$.

Since $AIJ_A$, $BIJ_B$ and $CIJ_C$ are straight lines, we have $J_A=(r_a,b,c)$, $J_B=(a,r_b,c)$ and $J_C=(a,b,r_c)$, where $r_a$, $r_b$ and $r_c$ are parameters to be determined.

Since $J_BAJ_C$, $J_CBJ_A$ and $J_ACJ_B$ are straight lines, we have
$$
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
a & b & r_c \\
a & r_b & c
\end{vmatrix}
=bc-r_cr_b
\implies
r_br_c=bc\\
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
r_a & b & c \\
a & b & r_c
\end{vmatrix}
=ca-r_ar_c
\implies
r_cr_a=ac\\
0=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
a & r_b & c \\
r_a & b & c
\end{vmatrix}
=ab-r_br_a
\implies
r_ar_b=ab
$$

Solving, we have $(r_a,r_b,r_c)=\pm(a,b,c)$. Note that $(r_a,r_b,r_c)=+(a,b,c)$ implies $J_A=J_B=J_C=I$. We should take $(r_a,r_b,r_c)=-(a,b,c)$. Then we have $J_A=(-a,b,c)$, $J_B=(a,-b,c)$ and $J_C=(a,b,-c)$, which is exactly the barycentric coordinates of the excenters.

#### Question

I can finish the proof by using barycentric coordinates as given above. I would like to know if there is an elementary proof.

Comment: Please include your proof using barycentric coordinates, as it could provide insights for an alternative approach.

Comment: I guess the easiest proof is to show first that the three excenters satisfy the required conditions, then argue by contradiction that it's the only possible case: For instance, pick a different point $J_A'$ on the half line $AI$.

Comment: I must be dumb… I don't understand how the points _J_ have been constructed from _A_, _B_, _C_ & _I_ in such a way that _A_, _B_  & _C_ lie on the green lines.

Comment: @Blue I have add the solution by using barycentric coordinates.

Comment: @jpboucheron The construction works if and only if $J_A$, $J_B$ and $J_C$ are the excenters. This is exactly the statement to be proved in the problem.

Comment: @Yuta: [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) and the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) yield the result. Take $AJ_A$, $BJ_A$, $CJ_A$ to be concurrent cevians of $\triangle ABC$. (Likewise, the lines through $J_B$ and $J_C$.) Ceva relates ratios of segments determined by intersections with the triangle's side-lines; the ABT "calculates" the ratios determined by $AJ_A$, $BJ_B$, $CJ_C$. The algebra involved is quite like your barycentric argument; this is unsurprising, given that they rely on the same underlying principles.